# How to convert a big ontology from Turtle (.ttl) format to OWL/XML (.owl) format?

Tags: owl, ontology, turtle-rdf

I am using an ontology from a GitHub here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oeg-upm/gtfs-bench/master/ontology/gtfs.ttl

The ontology is provided in Turtle format, but I need to convert it to OWL/XML format.

I tried to use online converters that available here:
https://www.ldf.fi/service/owl-converter/
http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/tools/webapps/owl-syntax-converter/

However, both converters not working. How could I convert a big ontology from Turtle (.ttl) format to OWL/XML (.owl) format?

Comment: use a commandline tool that is able to write OWL/XML format - not that I understand why you would use that rarely used format at all. By the way, the kinked ontology is rather small if not tiny, even loading it in Protege and then saving it as OWL/XML is trivial. Or just use the Obo robot tool from commandline

Comment: This is a small enough ontology to be opened in [Protege](https://protege.stanford.edu/). Open .ttl in Protege and save as OWL/XML.

Comment: In which way are these 'not working'? Please add details of the issues seen. (That said, the owl syntax converter available online is very old, it uses version 3 of OWLAPI - that's around 10 years out of date)

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse The owl/xml that is produced by Protege is different from the format  that I need. For example, the class from Protege is defined as `<Declaration>
        <Class abbreviatedIRI="schema:PriceSpecification"/>
    </Declaration>`. The required format is     `<owl:Class rdf:about="http://schema.org#PriceSpecification"></owl:Class>`

Comment: Then what you refer to as OWL/XML is in fact RDF/XML. Hence, save as RDF/XML rather than OWL/XML.

Answer (score 0):

### GUI-based way

1. Get the [Protege Ontology Editor](https://protege.stanford.edu/software.php),
2. Download the file,
3. Open it in Protege (File -> Open)
4. Save as RDF/XML (File -> Save As... brings "Select ontology format" window, it contains dropdown list, choose "RDF/XML Syntax there"; name the file and click "Save")

### Python way

If you know python, which may be the case, if you're reading this site, you can convert Turtle into RDF/XML using [RDFLib](https://rdflib.dev/) python library.

1. Install rdflib (`pip install rdflib` (or `pipenv` or `conda`, whatever environment manager you use))
2. Open turtle file

   ```py
   from rdflib import Graph
   g = Graph()
   g.parse("gtfs.ttl", format="turtle")
   ```
3. Save it as RDF/XML

   ```py
   g.serialize(destination='gtfs.rdf', format='xml')
   ```